# Find what 'automatically resolved' conflicts were made in TFS

Tags: tfs

When checking in files into TFS I sometimes get an 'automatically resolved' message:

> No files checked in due to conflicting changes. These conflicting
>   changes have been automatically resolved. Please try the check-in
>   again.

I know I can turn off automatic resolution, but I don't mind this being on. However sometimes I want to know exactly what it did to resolve these issues.

Is there a way to get a list of these differences so I can check them before clicking check-in again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way I've found to accomplish this is to look at the Output Window, select "Source Control - Team Foundation", and scan the list for all files that were automatically resolved. Then for each file you can view history on the file in question, and look at the recent changes.

Answer (score -1):

Those files are still checked out. If you compare your local version to the server version you should see the diff.